# JMS message selector on Object message

Tags: java-8, jms, websphere-liberty, open-liberty, jms2

I working on liberty 18.0.0.2 with JavaEE 8 .
I created Custom jms object message like this :

```
public class MyTextMessage implements Serializable {
    private String text;
    private String destination;
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;

    public MyTextMessage(String text, String destination, LocalDateTime dateTime) {
        this.text = text;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public MyTextMessage() {
    }

    // Getter and Setter 

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyTextMessage{" +
                "text='" + text + '\'' +
                ", destination='" + destination + '\'' +
                ", dateTime=" + dateTime +
                '}';
    }
}
```

How can select on queue by object property ?
this is my code but not work :

```
JMSConsumer consumer = context.createConsumer(destination, "destination='abcdefg'");
 Message message = consumer.receiveNoWait();
 if (message != null) {
      MyTextMessage myTextMessage = message.getBody(MyTextMessage.class);
      System.out.println(myTextMessage);
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to select on the property of an ObjectMessage implementation which is technically part of the body of the message.  However, section 3.8.1 of the JMS 2 specification states:

> Message selectors cannot reference message body values.
>
> A message selector matches a message when the selector evaluates to true
> when the message’s header field and property values are substituted for their
> corresponding identifiers in the selector.

Therefore, you need to set a property on the message with a value you can select on (e.g. using [javax.jms.Message.setStringProperty("destination", "abcdefg")](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setStringProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)).

Comment: How can add header to this object ?

Comment: I provided an example in my answer as well as a link to the JavaDoc for the related method. Please clarify what additional details are necessary.